# "KeyValuePair is not defined" when invoking a method that requires that type as an argument

Tags: f#

I receive the following error when attempting to invoke the function, "columnHasStreak" using REPL:

> error FS0039: The type 'KeyValuePair' is not defined

I am attempting to run the following code using REPL:

module TicTacToe

```
open FsUnit
open NUnit.Framework
open System.Collections.Generic


[<Test>]
let ``some test to help me learn F#`` () =

    let columnHasStreak (column : list<KeyValuePair<int,bool>>) =
        column |> Seq.forall (fun cell -> cell.Value)

    let cells = [0..8]
    let connectCount = 3;
    let columns = [0..2];

    let grid = [for cell in cells -> (cell, true)] 
               |> Map.ofSeq

    let rowLocations = grid 
                       |> Seq.chunkBySize connectCount 
                       |> Seq.toList

    let columnLocations = [for i in columns -> rowLocations|> List.map (fun row -> row.[i])]

    let allColumnsHaveStreak = [for i in columns -> columnLocations.[i]] 
                               |> Seq.forall (fun column -> column |> columnHasStreak)
```

Can someone explain to me why I am receiving this error?

Comment: I don't get this error in my VS. Maybe you haven't sent the line `open System.Collections.Generic` to F# interactive window

Comment: Oh... didn't know that was required.

Comment: Petr, post your suggestion as an answer, and I will credit you with the answer.

Comment: It isn't strictly required. E.g. when you use the predefined [active recognizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) [`KeyValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340489.aspx), like thus: `let columnHasStreak column =
        column |> Seq.forall (fun (KeyValue(_,value)) -> value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get this error in my VS. Maybe you haven't sent the line open System.Collections.Generic to F# interactive window